# Unable to display byte[] image in thymleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I am unable to display byte image in thymleaf which is come from  database as blob then convert to byte[], when I fetch image from database that query successfully implemented, but it is unable to display in thymleaf  here below is code

**DaoImpl code**
 **this function in daoimpl for retriving image from database**

in this fuction by using query blob is selected from database then blob is cast in byte and byte directly send to controller

```
@Override
public byte[] stockProductMenData() 
{
    Session session = getSession();

    byte[] Imagebytes = null;
    Query query = session.createQuery("select sp.stockProductPic "
            + "from StockType st,StockProduct sp"
            + " where st.stockTypeId=sp.stockTypeId and st.stockTypeName = :stockTypeName");
    query.setParameter("stockTypeName","MEN");



     List<Blob> list = query.list();
     System.out.println("List size :"+list.size()); 

     Iterator<Blob> itr = list.iterator();

      while(itr.hasNext())
      {  
         Blob blob = itr.next();
         try {
            Imagebytes =blob.getBytes(1,(int) blob.length());
            System.out.println("dddddd"+Imagebytes);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("eeeeeee"+e);
        }
      }
```

**controller** 
 in controller  we recieve byte  array and encoded in base64 and send to thymleaf page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mens" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView custMen()
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView =new ModelAndView();

    byte[] picContent = customerDao.stockProductMenData();
    byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(picContent);
    System.out.println("ssssssssss"+picContent);



                modelAndView.addObject("pic",encoded);
                modelAndView.setViewName("mens");
                return modelAndView;

}
```

**Front end with thymleaf**
here we recieve object of pic and display using thymleaf but pic is  not display

```
    <a href="mens_single.html">
    <div class="cbp-pgitem a3ls">
      <div class="cbp-pgitem-flip">
                            <img alt="Image"  th:field="${pic}" width="250" height="250"/>


   </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you sent a byte[] to be stored in your DB ....

1. Add the ***Base64 encoded string to your model map***:

   ```
   //I'm using a model here but the concept is the same
    model.addAttribute("pic",Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(*your_blob*));
   ```
2. In your thymeleaf snippet:

   ```
   <img th:src="${pic} == null ? _ : @{'data:image/png;base64,'+${pic}}">
   ```

Thymeleaf's template engine will facilitate converting your Base64 string into an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code

```
Blob imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob(yourBlobColumnIndex);
byte[] imageBytes = imageBlob.getBytes(i, (int) imageBlob.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the blob into bytes and then convert that bytes into Base64String using 
`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byte[] image);` gives Base64String which needs to be set in Context as variable and add a key using `context.setVariable(key, Base64String variable);` and then pass it in Template Engine for processing and add this line in Thymeleaf html page
`<img th:src="@{'data:image/png;base64,' + ${Base64String's key} }" />`

This approach works for adding Images, Qr Codes and BarCodes etc on the condition that they can be converted to byte[] for further processing.